# Multiple apps setup in firebase project for firebase cloud messaging. (React-native-firebase android)

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I have an app with 5 different product markets and each of them has 8 different builds. So i have 40 various package names for example:
`com.companyName.appName.marketName.dev`.

As mentioned in https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file:
*When processing the JSON file for your Android app, the plugin only uses the client object that matches your package name (for the current build type)*

Problems arising from adding more than 40 apps (+ iOS apps) to a firebase project:

1. Complication on adding more than 30 apps in firebase project as that is a limit. To raise the limit seems complicated. https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#apps-per-project
2. Maintenance (I would need to add additional apps if a new market would be introduced)

There is no need for me to have that many apps as i only need 1. ( I have omitted anything related to production app as it would reside in another firebase project)

I have added one apple app with an apple bundle id `com.companyName.appName` and it works for all suffixes.
I have tried doing the same with android, but i get an error:

`* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processCompanyNameMarketNameDevelopmentDebugGoogleServices'.  No matching client found for package name 'com.companyName.appName.marketName.dev'`

Is there a way to have a package name as a wildcard as in  `com.companyName.appName.*` or at least with marketName `com.companyName.appName.marketName.*` to work with all build types?
I have added one apple app with an apple bundle id `com.companyName.appName` and it works for all suffixes. All ideas welcome.